# Непонятное приведение типов при считывнии байтов в массив

Tags: c, массивы

Возникла проблема при считывании файла.
Корректно открывается необходимый файл с атрибутами "rb" через стандартную функцию fopen. Происходит чтение через:

```
char ch = getc(input_file);
```

В среде через `sizeof(char)` проверяю, что этот тип занимает 8 байт.
Работает некорректно...

Выясняется (с помощью `printf`), что периодически (или, скорее, стохастически) следующий байт считывается совершенно некорректно. Ниже привожу "сырой" бинарный дамп файла в формате Little-Endian, и рядом - значения, которые мне "выплевывает" соответствующая функция, со смещениями

```
Смещение  Исходное значение (LE)       Показываемое значение (LE)
0x100     73 00 00 00                  73 00 00 00
0x204     00 7D 00 00                  00 7D 00 00
0x208     CE 03 00 00                  FFFFFFCE 03 00 00
0x20C     EB 09 00 00                  FFFFFFEB 09 00 00
0x210     05 00 00 00                  05 00 00 00
0x214     C7 3A CE 3F                  FFFFFFC7 3A FFFFFFCE 3F
0X318     CE 80 00 00                  FFFFFFCE FFFFFF80 00 00
0X31C     12 01 00 00                  12 01 00 00
0X320     F2 01 00 00                  FFFFFFF2 01 00 00
0X324     05 00 00 00                  05 00 00 00
0X328     C7 3A CE 3F                  FFFFFFC7 3A FFFFFFCE 3F
```

Насколько я могу судить, система такова: если считанное число (`char ch`) меньше 0x80, то оно "остается" таким же, каким и было, а если больше или равно, то каким-то образом (каким именно, мне очень интересно) "добивает" до 32 (разрядность x86?) "слева" единицами...

Также интересно, что я считываю все это дело в двумерный массив `char arr[][]`, а потом передаю и так далее... Но почему компилится именно так, если `sizeof(char) == 1`?!

В конце концов, что делать с программой? не использовать же маску каждый раз, когда `char ch >= 0x80`? Что будет более эффективно и корректно, или как можно вовсе избежать всего этого дела?

Заранее благодарен за ответы!

На всякий случай:
Язык: чистый C
IDE: C-Free Professional 5.0 + mingw5

Comment: А как вы выводите? Покажите воспроизводящий код. `FFFFFFC7` не может быть значением _байта_. Да, и не забывайте, что `printf` как variadic function расширяет свои char-параметры до `int`'а. Пробовали просто при выводе закастить в `unsigned char`? Дкмаю, проблема не в чтении, а в выводе.

Comment: Вывод обычный:

printf("%x", arr[...][...]);

Важно, что я пытался затем этот массив передать в функцию и записать полученные байты как 32-битные числа, и мне это не удалось... Даже используя сдвиги не могу получить корректные значения.

Comment: @DumbStudent2016  sizeof(char) всегда равно 1. О каком типе вы говорите? Приведите минимальный проверяемый пример, который воспроизводит проблему.

Answer (score 2):

Попробуйте выводить так:

```
printf("%x\n", (unsigned char)c);
```

Вот такой код:

```
char c = 0x81;
printf("%x\n", c);
printf("%x\n", (unsigned char)c);
```

выводит

```
ffffff81
81
```

([Проверка](http://ideone.com/RI8Nrk).)

---

Дело в том, что у вас `char` знаковый. Функция `printf`, как и всякая вариадическая функция, расширяет свои `char`-аргументы до `int`. При расширении `char`-значения с взведённым старшим битом до `int` получается отрицательный результат — знаковый бит «размножается».

Думаю, вам стоит либо пользоваться `unsigned char`, либо провести приведение типов при выводе.

Comment: Вижу, но все, к сожалению, не так просто; я пытался затем этот массив передать в функцию и записать полученные байты четверками как 32-битные числа, и мне это не удалось... Даже используя сдвиги не могу получить корректные значения:

arr[...][...] + (arr[...][... + 1] << 8) + (arr[...][... + 1] << 16) + (arr[...][... + 1] << 24) тоже дает неверные значения

Comment: @DumbStudent2016: А битовый сдвиг тоже выполняет расширение до `int`, если мне не изменяет память. Попробуйте так: `arr[...][...] | ((arr[...][... + 1] << 8) & 0xff00) | ((arr[...][... + 1] << 16) & 0xff0000) | ((arr[...][... + 1] << 24) & 0xff000000)`.

Comment: Спасибо! После смены типа массива с char на unsigned char код заработал корректно!


Тем не менее, я до сих пор не понял: 1. почему при форматированном выводе с "%x" переменная char имеет 4 байта; 2. почему при инверсии происходит "добивание" единицами?

Например, если char ch == C7, то выводится именно FFFF.FFC7; но так как C7 = 1100.0111.b, то тогда должно было бы выводиться (так как 0x100 - 0xC7 = 0x39) FFFFFF39?

Comment: @DumbStudent2016: (1) Потому что при вызове функций типа `printf`, которые объявляются через `...`, все `char` или там `short`-аргументы превращаются в `int`. И в функцию уже приходит `int`. Почему так — спросите у Кернигана и Ричи, в других языках не так.

Comment: @DumbStudent2016: (2) А здесь язык C не при чём, это особенности хранения 16-ричных чисел в [дополнительном коде](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%94%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9_%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B4_(%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5_%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B0)). Отрицательное число хранится так же, как положительное, которое получено из него прибавлением `2^32` (или если хотите, хранится вычет по модулю `2^32`).

Comment: @DumbStudent2016: Смотрите: в байтах `0xA3 + 0x5D == 0x100`, это соответствует тому, что `-93 + 93 == 0`. Точно так же `0xFFFFFFA3 + 0x5D == 0x100000000`, это соответствует тому, что `-93 + 93 == 0` как целые числа.

Comment: @VladD *"Почему так"* - видимо, потому, что завязано на минимальном размере запихуемого в стек (при передаче аргументов по значению).

Comment: @PinkTux: Угу, это да. Но это ограничение _можно_ было бы обойти, если бы передавать скрытым образом ещё и размер. Ну да, пострадала бы эффективность. Учитывая философию языка C как переносимого ассемблера, смысл решения понятен.